# Passing a null object to mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

First off I'm very new to mockito.
I happened to overload a couple of methods in a legacy code base, that I was working on. However, as a result I had to change the test classes in order to make sure that the earlier test methods still called their original(intended) methods, one of the methods was passing in a null object earlier and as a result of the overloading, I had to do a cast ie.
`Throwable(null)` in the caller, and make a corresponding change in the verify event. So something like

```
ABCClass.logWarn(null,WarningString, description, (Throwable)null);
verify(event).setStatus(IsNull(Throwable.class));// this throws a compiler error asking me to create a method IsNull<Throwable>
```

Any thoughts on how I should fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think this would work:

```
verify(event).setStatus((Throwable)null);
```

Comment: Nope,that was the first thing I tried. It compiles fine, but maven throws a `Null Pointer` , when I run the test cases on those lines.

Comment: is `Event` final or is `Event.setStatus` final or private?  I think the above is the right answer but you have another problem.  There should be no NPE on the verify line, unless it is actually calling through to the real version of `event.setStatus()`, which doesn't happen unless Mockito is not able to fully mock the setStatus method.

Comment: and also, make sure `event` is actually a (non-null) Mockito mock, or it definitely won't work.  Did you check if `event` is non-null?  If you are using the @Mock annotation, a common thing to forget is either to extend the Mockito test runner or alternatively to invoke the MockitoAnnotations.init()

Comment: `Event` is not private, and `Event.setStatus` is public. The NPE is thrown on `ABCClass.logWarn(null,WarningString, description, (Throwable)null);`.

Comment: Well then you have another problem, but the solution I provided is the appropriate one to get you past the posted compiler error, which is what I thought the problem was.

Comment: Im using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`..Doesnt that suffice?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35379/discussion-between-kevin-welker-and-kodeseeker)